# How we can discontinue the session in dialogflow ES?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

In Dialogflow ES, I would like to terminate or close a specific session when the user reaches the end of the conversation or when a particular intent is triggered. This means that any message sent by the customer afterwards will be treated as the initial message and will be displayed in a new row in the Dialogflow history.

How we can achieve this?